# How can I use a cronjob when another program makes the commands in the cronjob fail?

Tags: cron, vps, cp, cd

I have a cron job which `cd` into a directory and performs actions.

For example:

```
0 12,00 * * * cd /var/lib/test/0001 && cp *.zip /home/bobby/
```

However, the program that creates the .zip files in `/var/lib/test/0001` changes the directory name every day. So on the second day, the directory is `/var/lib/test/0002` and on the third day `/var/lib/test/0003` and so on. This model cannot be changed.

Of course, when the directory migrates from `0001` to `0002`, the cronjob fails.

Is there a way to use cron to `cd` into `000*` and then `001*` and so on so that the `cp` command will be run? Perhaps there is an alternative way? Thank you.

EDIT MARCH 13:

There is another issue that I am finding hard to solve.

I only want to `cp` files that are above a certain filesize. I want to copy .zip files to `/home/bobby/` which are more than 28,000 bytes. If they are less than 28,000 bytes, then they don't get copied. How would I do this, thanks?

As before, this would happen in `/var/lib/test/****` (where `****` goes from `0000` to `FFFF` and increments every day).

Comment: Is this the last directory created in `/var/lib/test/ you want to go?

Comment: All the directories are created in /var/lib/test. Every day there will be a new one e.g. /var/lib/test/0178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with sample script:

```
dir=$(ls -tr1 /var/lib/test|tail -1)
cd /var/lib/test/$dir && cp *.zip /home/bobby/
```

`ls` get the list of files sort by time in reverse order so the last one is the last directory. And then we use it further.

Comment: I've updated the question. Could you please take a look if possible?

Comment: @user203748, please create new question pointing this one as reference

Comment: I have created a new question, thanks. It's at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677799/how-to-perform-a-cronjob-only-when-a-file-is-greater-than-a-certain-size