# How to perform a cronjob only when a file is greater than a certain size?

Tags: cron, vps, cp

The following script (credit to Romeo Ninov) selects the most recent directory and performs a `cp` operation:

```
dir=$(ls -tr1 /var/lib/test|tail -1)
cd /var/lib/test/$dir && cp *.zip /home/bobby/
```

Please see: [How can I use a cronjob when another program makes the commands in the cronjob fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60627504/how-can-i-use-a-cronjob-when-another-program-makes-the-commands-in-the-cronjob-f) for the previous question.

I would like to modify this so that the `cp` only happens if the .zip file is larger than a defined byte size e.g. 28,000 bytes. If the .zip file is smaller, nothing is copied.

As before, this would happen in `/var/lib/test/****` (where **** goes from `0000` to `FFFF` and increments every day).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your script on this way:

```
dir=$(ls -tr1 /var/lib/test|tail -1)
cd /var/lib/test/$dir
for i in *.zip
 do
 if [ "$(stat --printf="%s" $i)" -gt 28000 ] 
  then cp $i /home/bobby
 fi
done
```